# I'm getting confused with python imports

Tags: python, import

I have the following project structure:

[image]

within `blog_posts.py` I have the following function and router:

```
# blog_post.py

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/blog",
    tags=["blog"]
)

def required_functionality():
    return {"message": "Learning FastAPI is important"}
```

within `blog_get.py` I also have a router and import the `required_functionality` function:

```
# blog_get.py

from blog_posts import required_functionality

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/blog",
    tags=["blog"]
)

a = required_functionality()
```

Finally inside `main.py` im importing both routers:

```
# main.py

from router import blog_get, blog_posts

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(blog_get.router)
app.include_router(blog_posts.router)
```

If I then run main.py I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UKGC\PycharmProjects\FastAPI\Routers\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from router import blog_get, blog_posts
  File "C:\Users\UKGC\PycharmProjects\FastAPI\Routers\router\blog_get.py", line 4, in <module>
    from blog_posts import required_functionality
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog_posts'
```

If i then change the import in `blog_get.py` to:

```
# blog_get.py

from router.blog_posts import required_functionality

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/blog",
    tags=["blog"]
)

a = required_functionality()
```

and run `main.py` again I have no issues, however, if I run `blog_get.py` directly I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UKGC\PycharmProjects\FastAPI\Routers\router\blog_get.py", line 4, in <module>
    from router.blog_posts import required_functionality
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'router'
```

How can I get `main.py` and `blog_get.py` to both work? I clearly don't seem to understand python imports properly, can someone explain what I'm missing?

I've tried converting router to a package, I've tried relative imports.

Comment: missing `__init__.py` in folder router.

Answer (score 1):

You should use relative imports, not absolute imports

```
# blog_get.py

from .blog_posts import required_functionality
```

When you execute `main.py`, there is no directory on your module search path that contains `blog_posts.py`. But there *is* a module `router.blog_posts`, and `blog_get` (which tries to import `blog_posts`) is in the package `router` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution above only works when running from `main.py` and doesnt work from `blog_get.py`. After some reading I found a solution that works for both. @chepner

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run both scripts and get them to work I needed to append the 'router' to `sys.path` when importing from `main.py`. This is a bit of a hacky solution, im still open to other solutions?

```
# main.py
from router import blog_get, blog_posts

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(blog_get.router)
app.include_router(blog_posts.router)
```

and

```
# blog_get.py
import os
import sys
fpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(fpath)

from blog_posts import required_functionality

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/blog",
    tags=["blog"]
)

a = required_functionality()
```